# How to create a function with UITableViewCell as parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm wondering if we can make a dynamic function to access the cell template (xib template) for dynamic like this:

```
func create_image(TemplateName:??? = TemplateCell) {
    var cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: currindexpath as IndexPath) as! TemplateName
}
```

I want to pass the "TemplateName" with the name of class of UITableViewCell:

```
class template1: UITableViewCell {
}
```

so on that parameter I can pass any template cell that I made. Is that possible? Sorry if hard to explain.

Comment: why do you need to create a separate function ? You can use closures as delegates within cell class.

Comment: hmm sorry if i am not right to answer this..because possibility each row cell have different template layout...so i need to create this dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: no. Swift is not dynamic in the way that you would like. The only thing that can go after `as!` is an actual literal type name — not some sort of reference to a type that you would pass in a variable or parameter.

You could, as an alternative, dequeue the cell and then *ask* what type the cell is, thus casting down safely and explicitly:

```
let cell = // ... dequeue the cell as a UITableViewCell
if let cell = cell as? MyTableViewCell {
    // here, cell is a MyTableViewCell now
}
```

Using a switch statement instead of `if`, you could do that for all your different cell subclasses.

Comment: seems to be right...still need to be manually to compare between it...so there's no way to do that..thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
I have done this in one my sample project: Here is the sample code-

    func setCardLayoutAccordingToId(cell: UITableViewCell,layoutId:Int) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cgRect: CGRect = cell.contentView.frame
        var layoutView: Any = DefaultCardView(frame: cgRect)

        switch layoutId {
        case 1:
            layoutView = DefaultCardView(frame:cgRect)

        case 2:
            layoutView = Template_1(frame:cgRect)

        case 3:
            layoutView = Template_2(frame:cgRect)

        case 4:
            layoutView = Template_3(frame:cgRect)

         default:
            layoutView = DefaultCardView(frame:cgRect)
            (layoutView as! DefaultCardView).setData(cardData: data)
        }

       for view in (cell.contentView.subviews)!{
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1)?.addSubview(layoutView as!  UIView)

(layoutView as! UIView).translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let attributes: [NSLayoutAttribute] = [.top, .bottom, .right, .left]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(attributes.map {
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: (layoutView as! UIView), attribute: $0, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: (layoutView as! UIView).superview, attribute: $0, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)})
return cell }
```

P.S: layout_Id can be decided as per your need.

Comment: hi yes..so we still need to manually to catch the layoutID, i wish can just directly using the class name to pass the parameter..but this is great example..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `TemplateCell` in a function indeed. For example:

```
func yourMethodForCell(_ cell: TemplateCell){

    cell.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

Then call as follows:

```
yourMethodForCell(cell)
```